# What is this strange pattern being drawn

Tags: ios, graphics, rendering, render, metal

So I am creating a 2D app where circles are drawn onto an accumulation buffer. The buffer simply stores its contents and then the next frame it is faded and re-rendered over with new content creating a trailing effect.

I have noticed this odd pattern when I draw everything at a low resolution and I cant quite explain it.

[image]

And here is [a video](https://youtu.be/3YFNTx30Yy0) of it in action.

Currently, everything is drawn without depth sorting and alpha blending does not happen except for the fading. The circle is drawn with a quad that simply has the outside of it discarded in the fragment buffer.

Comment: Looks like a Moiré pattern—a common aliasing artifact.

Comment: Agreed. I would try to enable MSAA and see if that helps.